# Appear question mark �1��� in content html?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node to load html page from url. Here is my code:

```
request({
    url : url,
    timeout: 2000
}, function(error, response, html){
   console.log(html);
});
```

But when I run it appear strangle character �1���. I think this is not UTF-8. How can I fix it.

example url:  http://news.zing.vn/Nhung-hinh-anh-giau-cam-xuc-o-vong-17-VLeague-post560640.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the server is returning the responses in compressed format (gzip), even when you don't specifically ask for it through request-headers.

To fix, you can use the `gzip` option of `request`:

```
request({
    url     : url,
    gzip    : true,
    timeout : 2000
}, function(error, response, html){
   console.log(html);
});
```